# Why does my desktop look much worse after upgrading to windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8, integrated-graphics

I upgraded to 8.1 from 8 the other day, and while I can't prove it it seems like the desktop graphics (AMD Radeon) look *much* worse. It's a weird effect kind of like pixellation but not quite - almost as if there was 2d anti-aliasing that got turned off somehow.

Anyone else see this? If so, anyone find a fix?

What I have

[image]

What I want

[image]

Comment: Can you at least put a screenshot or something? It's not clear what you are talking about.

Comment: It's worth noting that the upgrade to Windows 8.1 also upgrades your graphics drivers in every instance I've come across so far. This was especially noticed on Arqade where [nVidia's Stereoscopic 3D settings were enabled as a result of upgrading to Windows 8.1](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/136412/52800) - this change in drivers is likely the cause of your issues as well.

Comment: Are you using the 13.9 stable drivers?  Those are the first stable drivers to include support for Windows 8.1.

Comment: That picture to me looks like 8-bit color depth, not sure of that was intentional or not (other than that it looks better than the 2nd one...)

Comment: Propose a metric or unit for "worse" or "much" or "weird" or "pixellation" or "not quite". Go on, I dare you. ;)

Comment: @Coldblackice, notice how in your case you were asking for a general definitive statement about all hard drives whereas I was asking about a specific problem with my system?

Comment: @jamesson Actually, if you'd read the question, I wasn't asking for a definitive statement :) Regardless, you (first) chided me for a nonstandard metric -- whether you're asking about your system or not, you're still asking for something without any standardized metric, and in an opinion-based format (adding pictures gave objectivity). What's "much worse" to you may be "no problem" to someone else, or a "catastrophic failure" to another.

Answer (score 1):

Set the [DPI Scaling back to 100%](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/extremewindows/archive/2013/07/15/windows-8-1-dpi-scaling-enhancements.aspx) to get the same view like in Windows 8.

[image]