# Desktop applications appear blurred after upgrading to Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, scaling

I've upgraded my Microsoft Surface Pro to Windows 8.1 two days ago. Now on my home monitor (native max and effective res is 1920x1200) all the desktop windows, except for browser rendered screens, appear as blurred.

It is as if the compilte-time provided raster window elements are not big enough and have to be scaled by the system. This looks absolutely annoying. Please take a look at the screen shot. I hope given the compression you will still be able to get the sense of what I am taking about:

[image]

At the same time the taskbar icons don't appear as blurred. Please assist how I can work around this cool new feature and have my windows displayed sharp again.

Comment: Believe it or not I just posted a question about how to go back to this.

http://superuser.com/questions/662794/why-does-my-desktop-look-much-worse-after-upgrading-to-windows-8-1

For me, upgrading to 8.1 had the exact opposite effect. 8.0 was blurry the way yours is, but I found that somewhat restful and want to go back :/

Comment: It's worth noting that the upgrade to Windows 8.1 also upgrades your graphics drivers in every instance I've come across so far. This was especially noticed on Arqade where [nVidia's Stereoscopic 3D settings were enabled as a result of upgrading to Windows 8.1](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/136412/52800) - this change in drivers is likely the cause of your issues as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can fix it by clicking right button on the app -> compatibility -> choose "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings" , but i am not sure what is causing it in general, looking for some solution also